# Duplicate Button in LinearLayout via Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-broadcastreceiver

I have created a Fragment that uses a Receiver to take in data and present it dynamically (@runtime) on the View. However, everytime the receiver gets new data, the buttons get created and the view is not overriden, but added on with the previous button. The main problem lies within the Fragment class, as I have tested TextViews. Help me find the problem with this Fragment:

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

    SDReceiver sdr;
    View v;
    TextView tx;
    LinearLayout main_layer;

    public OneFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        tx = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.result);
        main_layer = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.dynamic_layout);
        setupServiceReceiver();
        onStartService();
        return v;
    }

    public void onStartService(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ServiceHandler.class);
        intent.putExtra("receiver",sdr);
        getActivity().startService(intent);
    }

    public void setupServiceReceiver() {
        // Setup GUI by accessing objects from ArrayList
        sdr = new SDReceiver(new Handler());
        sdr.setReceiver(new SDReceiver.Receiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                try{
                    HashMap<Integer,String[]> resultValue = (HashMap<Integer,String[]>) resultData.getSerializable("itemList");
                    for(int i=0;i<resultValue.size();i++){
                        String data[] = resultValue.get(i);
                        String resultString = data[1] + ", " + data[2] + ", " + data[3] + ", " + data[4] + "\n";

                        Button button1 = new Button(v.getContext());
                        button1.setId(i);
                        button1.setText(resultString);
                        //button1.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(button1));

                        main_layer.addView(button1);
                        //tx.setText(bee);
                    }
                }catch(NullPointerException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //tx.setText(values);
            }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the old Buttons from your `LinearLayout` before adding the new ones. You can use [removeAllViews()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViews()) method:

```
main_layer.removeAllViews(); // to remove the old Buttons
for(int i=0;i<resultValue.size();i++){// then you can loop to add the new ones
     String data[] = resultValue.get(i);
     String resultString = data[1] + ", " + data[2] + ", " + data[3] + ", " + data[4] + "\n";

     Button button1 = new Button(v.getContext());
     button1.setId(i);
     button1.setText(resultString);
     main_layer.addView(button1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, assign a value to a variable does not mean your recreated a view, already drawn on a screen.
First, try to remove already added button by `main_layer.removeView(button1)` and then create and add a new one

Comment: Also setting id by button1.setId(i) is far not what you thing) 
setId() method geting as a parameter an integer which is refference to a preveously generated resource file, while view id must be a string, and there is more difficult to specify it programaticaly, you should better use setTag() method